# Make sexp-at-point ignore ";" in LaTeX mode

Tags: sexp

I have this LaTeX code:

```latex
$K(U_1, V_1, x_1; t_2, x_2)$
```

I found that the string/expression `(U_1, V_1, x_1; t_2, x_2)` is not recognized as an s-expression by the command (sexp-at-point) (in `latex-mode`) because of the symbol ";".

I think I should modify the syntax-table but I don't know how to do it.

I tried `C-h s` and I found:

```
: .. ;      .   which means: punctuation
```

Comment: Made ar-delimited-atpt for these occasions: https://github.com/andreas-roehler/thing-at-point-utils

Comment: @AndreasRöhler is there a way to get the same result by just modifying the syntax table?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a bug in `sexp-at-point`? If `point` is on the opening paren and I do `forward-sexp` it goes to the closing `$`, so the whole thing is apparently recognized as  an sexp.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Point is the notion of `sexp`. Reading: The word “sexp” is used to refer to an expression in Lisp. However, if at first char "a" in a string "asdf asdf", command `forward-sexp`  would stop at the whitespace after first "f". Counts that part of a literal as expression? Etc.